# Health insurance deduction - better to buy through S-Corp or individually?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, healthcare, s-corporation

I have a S-Corp that I can buy myself insurance through.  If my monthly coverage costs $380, is it more advantageous for me to purchase this insurance through my S-Corp and then use it as an employee benefit, or better for me to buy the insurance as an individual and take deductions on my personal return?

I am looking to see which option is more advantageous net of all taxes and deductions (payroll, income, FICA).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran this through my accountant and it's the same whether you do it through your company or as an individual.  The only difference is the line number where it occurs.